# Need help in making the left side of the button flow left

Tags: html, css

I am pretty new in web development and I am trying to make an affect on a left button that when you hover over it there is a smaller arrow appearing and the whole button expand into the left side of the screen, but for some reason it doesn't look as smooth as I want it too look and I can't find a way to make it that way, can someone help me? :)
PS:Rmain is the arrow always displayed on the button, Rside is the arrow that appearing when you hover over the button.

html:

```
<button class="right">
        <span class="Rmain"></span>
        <span class="Rside"></span>
    </button>
```

css:

```
.left {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.863);
    border: 4px solid rgb(60, 57, 238);
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    padding: 145px 10px;
    margin: 50px;
    width: 55px;
    text-align: right;
    border-radius: 10%;
    position: absolute;
    transition: 0.6s;
}

.left:hover {
    box-shadow: 5px 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    background-color: rgb(60, 57, 238);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    opacity: 75%;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-left-width: 95px;
    transition: 0.6s;
}

.Lmain {
    position: absolute;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    top: 40%;
    right: 86%;
    font-size: 40px;
}

.Lmain::after {
    content: '\290C';
}

.Lside {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    height: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 40%;
    right: 58%;
    font-size: 39px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.Lside::after {
    content: '\2039';
}

.left:hover .Lside {
    right: 72%;
    transition: 1s;
    opacity: 1;
}

button:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but it looks better this way:

add `border-right-width:20px;` into .left:hover section of css

Comment: No not exactly, it does help in some way but it creates the effect of the background sliding to the left and i want the whole background to change at the same time when I hover

Comment: I see, try to replace `border-left-width` with `width` instead in the .left:hover section. That might be what you're looking for